# How to mount AFP share on macOS with ADSSO authentication?

Tags: python, macos, active-directory, kerberos, afp

I am trying to use `NetFSMountURLSync` to mount an AFP network share on a macOS machine, using ADSSO to authenticate against the server.

When using the `mount_afp` binary to do the mounting, it is sufficient to specify the share URL as `afp://;AUTH=Client%20Krb%20v2@<hostname>/<share>`, as documented in `man mount_afp`. However, I cannot find documentation on how to achieve that with `NetFSMountURLSync`. I prefer the NetFS-based method compared to `mount_afp`, because it does not require the mount point directory to exist before the mount.

I tried specifying `Client Krb v2` as the `username` parameter of the `NetFSMountURLSync` call but nothing like that seems to work. Has anyone solved this before by any chance?

For full context, I'm calling the routine via Python's `objc`, loading the NetFS Framework as follows (inspired by [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/pudquick/e11b546d6ba9ebc2b604)):

```
import CoreFoundation
import Foundation
import objc
import sys

NetFS = {}
objc.initFrameworkWrapper('NetFS', frameworkIdentifier=None, frameworkPath=objc.pathForFramework('NetFS.framework'), globals=NetFS, scan_classes=False)

def mount_share_at_path_with_credentials(share_path, mount_path, username, password):
    # Mounts a share at the specified path, returns the mount point or raises an error 

    sh_url = CoreFoundation.CFURLCreateWithString(None, share_path, None)
    mo_url = CoreFoundation.CFURLCreateWithString(None, mount_path, None) if mount_path else None

    # Set UI to reduced interaction                                                                                                                                                                              
    open_options  = {
        NetFS["kNAUIOptionKey"]: NetFS["kNAUIOptionNoUI"],
    }
    # Allow mounting sub-directories of root shares 
    # Also specify the share should be mounted directly at (not under) mount_path 
    mount_options = {
                     NetFS["kNetFSMountAtMountDirKey"]: bool(mount_path),
                     "SoftMount": False,
                     NetFS["kNetFSMountFlagsKey"]: 0,
                    }
    # Mount! 
    result = NetFS["NetFSMountURLSync"](sh_url, mo_url, username or None, password or None, open_options, mount_options, None)

    # Check if it worked 
    print "OPEN OPTIONS: {}".format(open_options)
    print "MOUNT OPTIONS: {}".format(mount_options)
    if result != 0:
         raise Exception('Error mounting url "%s" at path "%s": %s' % (share_path, mount_path, result))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print sys.argv
    mount_share_at_path_with_credentials(*(sys.argv[1:]))
```

The arguments to the script are URL, mount-path, username, password; I'm specifying an empty mount-path to mount into a subfolder of `/Volumes`.